# Jupyter Notebook: annotation(s) lies/lay outside the given figure size

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to plot a pivot table as a bar chart, and Jupyter Notebook is giving me an error that I cannot quite understand.

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sex_pivot = train.pivot_table(index=["Sex", "Pclass"],values="Survived")
sex_pivot.plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

Here is the output:

```
<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x7f4dc25c1278>
<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x7f4dc22aaac8>
```

Here is my error message:

```
/dataquest/system/env/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/plotly/matplotlylib/renderer.py:522: UserWarning:

Looks like the annotation(s) you are trying 
to draw lies/lay outside the given figure size.

Therefore, the resulting Plotly figure may not be 
large enough to view the full text. To adjust 
the size of the figure, use the 'width' and 
'height' keys in the Layout object. Alternatively,
use the Margin object to adjust the figure's margins.

/dataquest/system/env/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/plotly/matplotlylib/renderer.py:487: UserWarning:

I found a path object that I don't think is part of a bar chart. Ignoring.
```

Can someone please tell me what I should type to solve this issue and display the diagram?

Answer (score 0):

I used %matplotlib notebook and it solved my issue.